# How to link search entries in v-combobox with its child component?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In the component below I am trying to make it so that the search value updates in both v-combobox and v-text-field (as in they are synced), however I've tried using .sync it hasn't worked.

How can I make it so that searching in v-combobox updates with the search functionality in v-text-field?

```
<v-combobox
    :items="allDropdownTypes.map(a => a.value)"
    label="Project Type"
    :search-input="search"
    small-chips
    hint="Select/Enter one option"
    persistent-hint
>
    <template v-slot:no-data> 
        <v-text-field
        class="paddingdropdown"
        label="Add new project type"
        hint="Press ENTER to add new item"
        persistent-hint
        small-chips
        prepend-icon="mdi-pencil"
        @keyup.enter="addToDropdown"
        >
        </v-text-field>
    </template>
</v-combobox>
```

Also:

```
data: () => ({
    search: null,
}),
```

Comment: Can't you just add a `:model="search"` to your `<v-text-field />` component?

Comment: Ah yes that works, thank you!